Time step (skipping) in CWT function with PyWavelets
I am using cwt function from pywavelet to perform time-frequency decomposition of a large signal (several million samples). The computational requirements for this is huge, sin it performs the calculation of the coefficient for every single sample (time step=1). In other languages such as labview (https://www.ni.com/docs/en-US/bundle/labview-advanced-signal-processing-toolkit-api-ref/page/lvwavelettk/wa_continuous_wavelet_transform.html), the function has a input variable, in labview for example is named "Time Step" to calculate of the coefficients skipping a number of samples. I do not see this option in PyWavelet, at least with this function. In addition, I do not see other function within Pywavelets to perform such analysis (time-frequency decomposition) skiping a number of samples. I believe this must be a common problem for everyone who needs to perform CWT for very large signals in python. Anyone knows if there is any solution for this issue? Thanks in advance
